# og meta Facebook & rails index: sharing info not updated in facebook share-box but correct in html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, facebook-opengraph, flush, meta

I'm using Facebook open graph meta tag inside one of my rails index view, which is an article post including a share on facebook link.

Everything worked well for the first post, and the facebook share box takes into account the meta provided (title, url, etc).
But when I want to share another post, then the facebook share-box keep the previous post info. In the html, the meta are good, and when I use facebook debug, everything is fine.

What I am missing ? There is a cache flush to do ?
Thank you a lot for the help

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<%= @post.title %> wanted on XXX!" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content= "Site Name" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://siteroot<%= display_path(@post) %>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Site is bla bla bla" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<%= @post.vignette.url(:medium) %>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/appname" />
<meta property="article:section" content="Responsive" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you're doing this or not but make sure you're sharing the post page and not the index page.

```
href="www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= @post.url %>"
```

The og tags in the head won't update without reloading the page, so you'll have to point Facebook to each post's unique url.